# SQL - Rank function

Tags: sql-server, ranking-functions

I am trying to rank data based off multiple factors and having trouble doing so.
I want to rank each Batch and Material based off the most recent entry date and max value material doc item. (So 2 over 1 etc)

[image]

In the above sample data I would expect row 5 to be ranked 1 as it is the most recent date with the highest material doc item.

Current Logic:

```
RANK () OVER (PARTITION  BY BATCH, MATERIAL ORDER BY BATCH, MATERIAL , ENTRY_DATE  , MATERIAL_DOC_ITEM DESC ) AS RANK_NUM
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: FYI, ordering on columns in your partition is pointless; all the values in that partition are going to be the same. `BATCH` and  `MATERIAL` do not need to be in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need DESC after the ENTRY_DATE as well to get most recent date. Also note no need to include batch and material in the order by as the ordering is within the partition

```
RANK () OVER (PARTITION  BY BATCH, MATERIAL ORDER BY ENTRY_DATE DESC, MATERIAL_DOC_ITEM DESC ) AS RANK_NUM
```

Comment: Yes this is working perfectly. Was stuck for the last hour on this and didn't know I needed to declare the order twice. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @tomfbsc, if the answer worked you should accept it, that helps future users who have a similar question quickly locate good solutions. Also, you're more likely to get people to invest time solving your future questions if you give credit for the good answers you get.